# Apache Axis - Java WS Client Code and SoapUI giving different responses

Tags: web-services, webservice-client, axis

We are facing a strange issue of getting different number of records as response while making the same webservice API call from our WS client code and SOAP UI.

Lets assume the WS API is something like `Foo[] getBar()` and it is supposed to return `2` records.

So when we are making a call from `SoapUI` we get two records but when our client code makes a call it is getting only one record.

I have grabbed the request XML posted by my WS client code from logs and used it to request from SoapUI.

Can it be an issue of an old client stubs?

PS: We are using Apache Axis.